# ReactJS: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image]

After using a form and inserting new data this error show up.

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import hashHistory from './hashHistory';


const FormItem = Form.Item;




class CustomForm extends React.Component {

  handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, articleID) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const postObj = {
      title: event.target.elements.title.value,
      content: event.target.elements.content.value
    }

    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
    axios.defaults.headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
    };

    if (requestType === "post") {
      await axios.post("http://192.168.196.49:8000/api/create/", postObj)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            //this.props.history.push(`/articles/`);
            //this.props.hashHistory.push('/');
            //hashHistory.push(String('/articles/'))
            this.props.history.push({
              pathname: "/"
           })

          }
        })
    } else if (requestType === "put") {
      await axios.put(`http://192.168.196.49:8000/api/${articleID}/update/`, postObj)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            //this.props.history.push(`/articles/`);
            //this.props.hashHistory.push('/');
            //hashHistory.push(String('/articles/'))
            this.props.history.push({
              pathname: "/"
           })
          }
        })
    }
  };

  render() {

    console.log("debug:", this.props)

    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          onSubmit={event =>
            this.handleFormSubmit(
              event,
              this.props.requestType,
              this.props.articleID
            )
          }
        >
          <FormItem label="Título">
            <Input name="title" placeholder="Put a title here" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="Comentario">
            <Input name="content" placeholder="Enter some content ..." />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              {this.props.btnText}
            </Button>
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomForm);
```

Routes

```
 <Route exact path="/articles/" component={ArticleList} />{" "} 
 <Route exact path="/articles/:articleID/" component={ArticleDetail} />{" "}
```

Error message:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

The data is storing correcty to the database, but just after submiting there is this error.

My original code was using history.push but tried hashHistory.push.

I am using redux in the proyect.

Verision using:
react-router 5.1.2
history 4.9.0

Comment: Did you re-configure the router to use hashHistory? why did you switch from history to hashHistory?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this.props)` in `render`, but above `return`? Do you have `history`, `match` and other Route component related props?

Comment: No i didn´t reconfigure router (how can I do it?) The reason that I switch to hashhistory is because i found googling that is a new way in newest version.

Comment: content of this,props: Form.js:51 debug: {requestType: "post", articleID: null, btnText: "Create", token: "bb07b03e3430ab5910c69e85e0fbdbd8af9c0ff6", dispatch: ƒ}requestType: "post"articleID: nullbtnText: "Create"token: "bb07b03e3430ab5910c69e85e0fbdbd8af9c0ff6"dispatch: ƒ ()__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make a module hashHistory:

```
// hashHistory.js
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'; // worked for the OP
export default createHashHistory({});
```

And use it:

```
const history = createHashHistory();
// ....

 // **EDIT** This should work
 history.push("/articles/")
```

Comment: I test it and aded to my form:        ` this.props.hashHistory.push('/'); `           and  this the error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Comment: See my edit Sorry oversaw this -> just copied your code ;-)

Comment: I made the change you are proposing ans have the same error:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Comment: Did you use pathname: "/" ? See my EDIT - that is a string! You have to use the double quotes not the single ones. If it still does not work post your refined code as edit to your question

Comment: Yes, I copy from here.

Comment: This is my routes:     <Route exact path="/articles/" component={ArticleList} />{" "}
    <Route exact path="/articles/:articleID/" component={ArticleDetail} />{" "}    and also tried with: /articles/.

Comment: I'll be back in app 3h

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210445/discussion-between-kentron-dna-and-codebreaker007).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withRouter` to push history in props.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const SpecialButton = withRouter(({ history, path, text }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => { history.push(path); }}
    >
      {text}
    </Button>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that works (may be is not the best one...)

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'


const FormItem = Form.Item;

class CustomForm extends React.Component {

  handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, articleID) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const postObj = {
      title: event.target.elements.title.value,
      content: event.target.elements.content.value
    }

    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
    axios.defaults.headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
    };

    const history = createHashHistory();

    if (requestType === "post") {
      console.log("debug_1.1_Form_post_history: ", history )
      await axios.post("http://192.168.196.49:8000/api/create/", postObj)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            history.push("/articles/")
          }
        })
    } else if (requestType === "put") {
      console.log("debug_1.2_Form_put_history: ", history )
      await axios.put(`http://192.168.196.49:8000/api/${articleID}/update/`, postObj)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log("debug_1.3_Form_put_this.props: ", this.props)
              history.push("/articles/");
          }
        })
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          onSubmit={event =>
            this.handleFormSubmit(
              event,
              this.props.requestType,
              this.props.articleID
            )
          }
        >
          <FormItem label="Title">
            <Input name="title" placeholder="Put a title here" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="Content">
            <Input name="content" placeholder="Enter some content ..." />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              {this.props.btnText}
            </Button>
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomForm);
```